What is Peirce's "interpretant"?
In trying to wrap my brain around the core notions of C.S. Peirce's semiotics, I have consulted both the Wikipedia article and the article at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, but I have found both of them pretty tough sledding.
I'm wondering if the following situation (of my own invention) is a reasonable way of thinking about his three components of a sign—its signifying element, object, and interpretant:

There are two particular signs S1 = (s1, o1, i1) and S2 = (s2, o2, i2). As it happens,
s1 = s2 = the utterance (sounding like) [i],
o1 = o2 = the logical connective AND,
i1 = the Spanish-language lexical convention that associates the utterance s1 to o1, and
i2 = the Russian-language lexical convention that associates the utterance s2 to o2.
Of course, when transcribed, S1 is written as "y," and S2 as "и."

Do I have this anything near right?

Note that general semiotics is not on-topic on this site, but only when it is applied to language.

That Wikipedia article is pretty clear: an interpretant is a sign's meaning, implication, or ramification. I am not sure what "a lexical convention" is in your definition.

Ah, @Lambie, this is far from the first time we have seen things differently. "Pretty clear"? To you, perhaps. If, as I suggested in my example, the signifying elements are the utterances, and, as you suggest, the interpretants are the meanings, then what are the respective objects of Spanish y and Russian и?

Paul, I asked you to provide an example. What makes you think I am disagreeing with  anything? The y in Spanish can join all manner of  things: adjectives, adverbs, nouns, noun phrases, verbs, verb phrases, gerunds. But is that lexical?
